# can anyone tell me how to handle windows pop up in selenium(save user name and pwd ) using java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
{
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:/chrome driver/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://app.mycable.in/#/login");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("mycable");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("mycable1");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Alert alert =driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(href='#/customer/')][text='restricted.customer']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='input']")).sendKeys("abcd");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Incognito mode in Chrome to avoid any alerts/notifications and Incognito is also secure in some ways. 
Just run the below code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException          
{
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("--incognito");
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
 WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
 driver.get("http://app.mycable.in/#/login");
 driver.get("http://app.mycable.in/#/login");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("mycable");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("mycable1");
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
 Thread.sleep(1000);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[contains(href='#/customer/')][text='restricted.customer']")).click();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='input']")).sendKeys("abcd");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid that Remember username and Password popup these piece of code may help full to you.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();    
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
chromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

There is no use of saving password everytime because at every time of execution new instance of driver will be invoked with no cookies or cache in it. Let me know if there is any issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for your question:

1. As per standard practices it is recommended not to use `Thread.sleep(1000)` instead use Implicitwait as below:

`driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

2. Save username/password is not an Alert. We will disable it using Options Class of Chrome as below:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\SeleniumUtilities\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
   Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
   prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
   prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
   options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
   options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
   options.addArguments("--enable-automation");
   options.addArguments("--disable-save-password-bubble");
   options.addArguments("test-type");
   options.addArguments("start-maximized");
   options.addArguments("test-type=browser");
   options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
   driver.get("http://app.mycable.in/#/login");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")).sendKeys("mycable");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys("mycable1");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='submit']")).click();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   ```

Using the following code with options for Chrome driver will help you to get rid of all issues.

Let me know if this helps you.